# How can I access to js requiring site by PHP http_request?

Tags: php, httprequest, pear

I'm using HTTP_Request of PEAR Library.
I want to access to https://www.valuecommerce.ne.jp/en/.
but, this site requires js when I access.

How can I enable js by using HTTP_Request? if it's not possible, do I have other ways?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm right it's not possible to enable JS via HTTP_Request.

You could try ...

```
// $html contains the source of the site you request
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.valuecommerce.ne.jp/en/');
```

... and check if the content you need is accessible in this variable

Comment: You couldn't access the url? Or not the variable you want to use? I tried my code and I get some HTML back.

Comment: oh, sorry. I wanted to access to https://www.valuecommerce.ne.jp/sys/login.cfm from https://www.valuecommerce.ne.jp/en/. after logged in, js is must.